# link_stat table and access tokens

Tags: facebook-fql

It says in the July 2013 roadmap that an access token is required to query the link_stat table.

Yet, when I use the URL below, I still get a result

```
https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.google.com'
```

Please can someone explain this to me?